# Is there a way to find the timestamp of a photo in an iPhone4, without syncing with a computer?

Tags: iphone, photos

Is there any way of figuring out when a photo on my iPhone4 has been taken, without first importing the photo to a Mac or PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's iPhoto application will allow you to get the image size, location, fstop, iso and timestamp of images taken with the phone.

The only downside to the app is that it costs $4.99.

Answer (score 3):

Since the available photo options within iOS are limited, I don't think it's possible without any 3th party software.

[King Camera](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/king-camera/id430240788?l=nl&mt=8) is such an app. It shows some meta data about every photo you took with the app.

Comment: The problem with that App is that it only gives info on photos taken with the app. I would like to get info about the photos already on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a free option, have a look at [EXIF Wizard](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/exif-wizard/id387652357?mt=8). It displays all EXIF attributes (including date/time) and also can use the GPS coordinates in a picture to show the location on a map.

Answer (score -1):

Dropbox can give you the time stamps.

Answer (score -2):

Drop box is definitely the way to go.